# Plotly in R: Specific colors for each category

Tags: r, plotly, heatmap

I'm trying to build a heatmap with data with data that looks like:

```
dataset <- data.frame(ID = c(rep('population', 8), rep('sub_population', 8)),
       TYPE = rep(c('one', 'two', 'three', 'for', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight'),2),
       COUNT = rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),2)
       ) %>%
mutate(TEXT = paste(TYPE, 'has:', COUNT))
```

My goal is to generate a Plotly Heatmap where the **IDs** are two separate rows in the heatmap with squares for each category/**TYPE**.

In each square I want the **COUNT** as text and when I hover the square I want to show the TEXT column.

The hard part is that I want to have specific colors for each categories (i.e. **TYPE**). For instance, TYPEs `one` through `three` are `gray`, `four` through `seven` are `red`, and `eight` is `blue`.

I now have:

```
plot_ly(
dataset,
x = ~TYPE,
y = ~ID,
z = ~COUNT,
hoverinfo = 'text',
text=~TEXT,
xgap = 5,
ygap = 5,
type = 'heatmap') %>%
add_annotations(text = ~COUNT,
                showarrow = FALSE,
                textangle = 45,
                font=list(color='white')
)
```

I've tried the tips given in: [Specifying the colors in a Plotly Heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44861851/specifying-the-colors-in-a-plotly-heatmap), but haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: https://community.plot.ly/t/custom-colorbar-range/1068

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

I've tried the following:
    custom_colors <- list(c(1, "rgb(255, 0, 0)"),
              c(2, "rgb(255, 0, 0)"),
              c(3, "rgb(255, 0, 0)"),
              c(4, "rgb(0, 255, 0)"),
              c(5, "rgb(0, 255, 0)"),
              c(6, "rgb(0, 255, 0)"),
              c(7, "rgb(0, 0, 255)"),
              c(8, "rgb(0, 0, 255)")
               )

And setting colors in the plotly-function to custom_collors. This, however, does not work. Am I defining the color list correctly? Of am I using it wrong in the plotly-function?