# R - ggplot, Change base color used by aes() for coloring according to ..n

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

This solution doesn't work: [R: ggplot heatmap color change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43133521/r-ggplot-heatmap-color-change)

I use ..n.. within aes(...) to use the count a coloring criteria.

I found no way to change the default color gradient (blue to darkblue) as it would be possible if a "normal" variable instead of ..n.. is used.

Normally I'd expect something like this (below) to work. But I found no way to refer to the used ..n.. in the scale_fill_gradient(...) call.

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=V1, y=V2))
+ geom_violin(scale="width",aes(color = ..n..))
+ scale_fill_gradient('n',limits=c(0, 100), breaks = c(0, 25, 50, 75, 100),  low = "red", high = "green")
```

The defalt gradient is still used instead of the defined gradient.

How can I change the gradient in use with the ..n.. critria ?

Comment: You are mapping `color` then setting a `fill` scale. Try `scale_color_gradient`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ggplot` there are two kinds of colour scale that you can specify in `aes()`: `colour` and `fill`. Your example does not work because you map a colour aesthetic, and specify a fill scale, two scales that are not more related to each other than the size, shape and alpha scales. One of these should work: either you do `aes(fill = ..n..)` or you use `scale_colour_gradient()`.

Comment: Thanks ! Worked like a charm. Tried so such. Also with fill and color ... somehow I missed the only working combination.